# Gstreamer change property with PARAM_MUTABLE_READY for PLAING pipeline

Tags: gstreamer

I'm using gstreamer-1.0 and Vala in my app in order to do some trickery with video processing. I'm using few elements which parameters have flag PARAM_MUTABLE_READY. Elements are connected together and the pipeline is PLAYING. At certain point I'd like to modify those properties so I'm doing as following:

- on the sink pad of this element i put a blocking UPSTREAM probe,
- then I set the element status to READY
- I apply some changes in properties marked with PARAM_MUTABLE_READY flag,
- I set element and pipeline status to PLAYING again,
- finally I remove blocking probe

The result is that pipeline does not re-play, its still in some uncertain state. What I'm trying to do is to have many branches of Gstreamer elements and ideally I would like not to pause whole pipeline but just selected parts of the graph.

I appreciate any help.